Error while fitting the model . Unknown error: Graph execution error
I'm running into this error while training the model. Couldn't find any specific solutions. Please help. This is the complete link to the codetext. Used T4GPU for executing the code.
The model is used to transcribe speech from lip movements. Used speaker 1 of the grid dataset. Please comment on the colab file if you find the mistake
This is the error message:
Epoch 1/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step
Original: set white with c seven again
Prediction: la e e e on
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Original: place blue in o six please
Prediction: la e e e o o
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
450/450 [==============================] - 915s 2s/step - loss: 84.2043 - val_loss: 70.6985 - lr: 1.0000e-04
Epoch 2/100
450/450 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 71.3770
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3f54ab0eeaa9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(train, validation_data=test, epochs=100, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, schedule_callback, example_callback])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51   try:
     52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node EagerPyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Detected at node EagerPyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 311040 values, but the requested shape has 3 [Op:Reshape]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 268, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 146, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 153, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "<ipython-input-8-369c148ab7ee>", line 8, in load_data
    frames = load_video(video_path)

  File "<ipython-input-5-d900040ec1b4>", line 8, in load_video
    frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 311040 values, but the requested shape has 3 [Op:Reshape]


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[CTCLoss/Shape_3/_4]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 311040 values, but the requested shape has 3 [Op:Reshape]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 268, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 146, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 153, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "<ipython-input-8-369c148ab7ee>", line 8, in load_data
    frames = load_video(video_path)

  File "<ipython-input-5-d900040ec1b4>", line 8, in load_video
    frame = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(frame)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 311040 values, but the requested shape has 3 [Op:Reshape]


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_1515170]


Hi@Ninja, The error you are facing shows that the shape mismatch, the tensor you are trying to reshape has 311040 elements but you are requesting it to be reshaped into 3 elements, conform that you are putting the correct shape,Thanks
